# Predefined layers inside Custom layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I want to use predefined layers from tf.keras.layers inside a custom layer. I want to create a custom layer that is a combination of dense and 1D Convolution layers.
Is it possible to do something like that? I could not find an example in the tensorflow pages.

Comment: Do you want to feed different data to these two layers separately or do you want to add these two layers, to which you will feed data?

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I understand that you want to leverage the class-base API to define your own building-block/layer/model that encapsulate two predefined layers.

```
import tensorflow as tf

class MyLayer(tf.keras.Sequential):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=[10], use_bias=False))  # Use a first predefined layer
        self.add(tf.keras.layers.Layer())  # Use a second predefined layer

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = MyLayer()
    print(l.summary())
    print(l(tf.constant([[0] * 10])))
```

However, best solution would be to inherit the `tf.keras.layers.Layer` class and to properly override the `call` method, but it probably takes more lines.

---

### Edit

Layer implementation is not so much difficult:

```
class MyLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, name="MyLayer", **kwargs):
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.layer1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, use_bias=False)
        self.layer2 = tf.keras.layers.Layer()

    def call(self, inputs):
        return self.layer2(self.layer1(inputs))
```

It requires it little bit more at instanciation:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    i = tf.constant([[0] *10])
    m_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(10,))
    l = MyLayer()
    m_output = l(m_input)
    m = tf.keras.Model(inputs=m_input, outputs=m_output)
    tf.print(m.summary())
    tf.print(m(i))
```

I think it is the right way to implement what you ask, but I never really grasp the difference between inheriting from `Model` or from `Layer`. Take a look at the [dedicated guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models) and give me your feedback!